# Calling Javascript from serverside , given form target not working

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, iframe, server-side

I am calling a Javascript from server side as given below,

`Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myScript", "crossDomainPost('a','b','c','d');", true);`

The javascript is written on client side as given below,

```
function crossDomainPost(StateCd, DistCd, CourtCd, Token) {
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.target = "my_iframe";
    form.action = "http://Somedomain/Somepage.php";
    form.method = "POST";
    form.name = "loginForm";
}
```

Now the problem is when I am calling the given javascript from server side the response is given in a new tab and not in an iFrame which is given form target for the response.

Note: When the same javascript is called from the client side I am getting the response in mentioned iFrame.

Please help me fixing this.
Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this,this.GetType(), "Warning", "crossDomainPost('a','b','c','d')", true);

```
       // if not Ajax Update panel
      this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Warning", "('a','b','c','d')", true);
```